# Обработчик .scroll для safari

Tags: jquery

Функция .scroll не корректно работает в сафари на ipad, есть её аналог для работы с мобильными устройствами?

Answer (score 1):

Это корректная работа `onScroll` на touch устройствах, другого события нет.
Но можно это обойти (http://jsfiddle.net/5PsYc/):

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (){
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
}, false);
```